# TypeError at /admin/myapp/mymodel when trying to access django admin, after I changed some model fields (Django)

Tags: django, model, typeerror, rename, admin

I am developing an app in Django.

It was working fine until I renamed some fields in my model.
I have run migrate and makemigrations.
Then, when I log in as admin ad try to access "mymodel" in section "myapp", this is what I get:

> **TypeError at /admin/myapp/glossary_entry/**
>
>   not enough arguments for format string

What's the problem?
(Everything else in my app works perfectly until it comes to access the model contents inside admin page)

I post the complete error message here:

> TypeError at /admin/myapp/glossary_entry/ not enough
>   arguments for format string Request Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myapp/glossary_entry/
>   Django Version:   2.2.2 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   not
>   enough arguments for format string Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy
>   Django\Myproject\myapp\models.py in **str**,
>   line 95 Python Executable:    C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.5 Python Path:   ['C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest
>   framework\Udemy '  'Django\Myproject', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\python36.zip', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages', 
>   'C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\pip-19.1.1-py3.6.egg']
>   Server time:  Sat, 28 Sep 2019 08:56:32 +0000 Error during template
>   rendering In template
>   C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html,
>   error at line 62
>
> not enough arguments for format string 52             {% endblock %}
>   53             54           {% endif %} 55          {% endblock %} 56
>   {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %} 57        58        59     {% block breadcrumbs %} 60       61       {% trans
>   'Home' %} 62      {% if title %} › {{ title }}{% endif %}
>   63         64       {% endblock %} 65       {% endif %} 66   67     {%
>   block messages %} 68          {% if messages %} 69            {% for message in messages %} 70            {{
>   message|capfirst }} 71           {% endfor %} 72            {%
>   endif %}

Here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from .models import glossary_entry 

admin.site.register(glossary_entry)
```

Here is my model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 


Admin_approval_switch_choices=[
    ("show","show"), # 1=valore da inserire negli script (=variabile), 2=valore assunto in relatà nel db
    ("hide","hide"),
    ]


class glossary_entry(models.Model):



    Lemma = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Acronimo = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    Definizione = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) 

    Ambito_riferimento = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Autore_definizione = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Posizione_definizione = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Url_definizione = models.URLField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

    Titolo_documento_fonte = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Autore_documento_fonte = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Host_documento_fonte = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    Url_documento_fonte = models.URLField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

    Data_inserimento_entry = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now().date() )

    Id_statico_entry = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, default="ITCH00000")



    Admin_approval_switch = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False, null=False, default=Admin_approval_switch_choices[1], choices=Admin_approval_switch_choices)



    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-Admin_approval_switch', 'Lemma', 'Id_statico_entry']

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.Lemma or self.Acronimo or self.Definizione or  self.Ambito_riferimento or self.Autore_definizione or self.Posizione_definizione or self.Url_definizione or self.Titolo_documento_fonte or self.Autore_documento_fonte or self.Host_documento_fonte or self.Url_documento_fonte):
            raise ValidationError("Non è stata inserita alcuna terminologia. Compilare almeno un campo del form.")

    def __str__(self):    
        return  "%s / %s - %s - [%s]"  %  (self.Lemma, self.Id_statico_entry, self.Admin_approval_switch)
```

Comment: Please show the full code for the model and the ModelAdmin class.

Comment: post updated. let me know if it is clear now, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

In the last line of class meta, in model.py:

```
def __str__(self):    
    return  "%s / %s - %s - [%s]"  %  (self.Lemma, self.Id_statico_entry, self.Admin_approval_switch)
```

There is a mismatch in "string inserting tags" and "inserting arguments" (excuse my bad english please).

I substituted the line with:

```
def __str__(self):    
    return  "%s - %s - [%s]"  %  (self.Lemma, self.Id_statico_entry, self.Admin_approval_switch)
```

and now averything works fine.

Comment: It was so easy actually, the error was pointing out: typer error at line 62, but it was pointing base.html instead of model.html.
Base.html contains a top navbar contents that is then shown in all pages of my project.